# Problem converting Ruby on Rails DateTime to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, datetime, nsdate

Why is this ...

```
NSString *mydate = @"2011-07-20T23:59:00-07:00"

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];

    NSLog(@"%@", [[dateFormatter dateFromString:mydate] description]);
```

... returning "(null)" in the console?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your date format of `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"` means that it's looking for a literal "`Z`" character at the end of the string.  However, your string is:

```
@"2011-07-20T23:59:00-07:00"
```

I don't see a "`Z`" there, do you?  Thus, the date comes back as `nil` because your string does not match the format specified.

According to the [Date Formatting Patterns documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns), you're probably looking for the format string of:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"
```

However, even *that* might not work, because if you notice your source string has a colon ("`:`") in between the hours and minutes of the timezone offset.  There's no timezone specifier that accounts for that.  If that is indeed the format in which ROR is returning the date, then ROR is wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately Rails is doing just that ... returning -07:00 instead of -0700.  This kinda sucks.  Take out the colon and all is well.

Comment: @wgpubs if you removed all the colons you could use `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmssZZ"` as your format string.

Comment: I went with something similar ... removing the last colon from the string (it's always in the same position relative to the length of the string).  Your solution seems a bit easier and more straight-forward though so I may go with it.  Thanks

Comment: FWIW, I was able to use ZZZZ with `2013-06-18T22:00:00-04:00`. It returned to me `2013-06-19 04:00:00 +0000`

Answer (score 0):

I am doing transfer of Dates from Ruby to iOS via a JSON API and I believe I have read the same article.

http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/

I am almost positive that they have mistakenly added the 'Z' as a string literal

-

To get Ruby to output as you are probably expecting I did the following:

```
 1.9.3-p392 :012 > s = Time.now
  => 2013-05-03 15:47:51 +0100 
 1.9.3-p392 :013 > s.strftime("%Y-%m-%d\T%H:%M:%S%:z")
  => "2013-05-03T15:47:51+01:00"
```

Notice the %:z that is available in Ruby 1.9.3 at least

[Is there a Ruby 1.8.7 time.strftime %z bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568923/is-there-a-ruby-1-8-7-time-strftime-z-bug)